# Creating new column based on letter in string

Tags: r

I want to create a new column in R based on the third letter of a string of a different column.

I'm working though data that I've recently gathered and rather than asking my participants to tick a box for their sex, I include it it their anonymised subject ID. Now I want to create a separate column of participant sex based on the third letter (m/f) in their code. I've looked around however, I've not been able to find a solution. I've managed to find that I can use 'separate (remove = FALSE)' and if possible I'd like to use that since I'm comfortable using tidyverse.

```r
# Example code

library(tidyverse)

a <- data_frame(SubjID = c("hgm9899", "lkf98988", "lkfm09078", "ujm987987"))
```

I'd like to add a column with the header participant_sex and M if the participant's third letter was m and F if it was f.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility could be:

```
a %>%
 mutate(participant_sex = toupper(substr(SubjID, 3, 3)))

  SubjID    participant_sex
  <chr>     <chr>          
1 hgm9899   M              
2 lkf98988  F              
3 lkfm09078 F              
4 ujm987987 M
```